# Is this a valid move in my simple inequality proof?

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

> Prove: $|x+y+z| \leq |x|+|y|+|z|/$

We have the theorem 1: $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$.

Let $a = x$ and $b = (y+z)$; thus by theorem 1 it follows: $|x+y+z| \leq |x|+|y+z|$,

$$|x+y+z|-|x| \leq |y+z|.$$

We know by theorem 1: $|y+z| \leq |y|+|z|$.

Thus we have: $|x+y+z|-|x| \leq |y+z| \leq |y|+|z|$.

Therefore by way of transitivity, we have: $|x+y+z|-|x| \leq |y|+|z|$.

Thus, $|x+y+z| \leq |x|+|y|+|z|$.

Comment: What is this « equal » sign, here? Why do you think you cannot judge the validity of your proof by yourself?

Comment: I just started learning proof writing, so I naturally have doubts judging validity.  Which sign are you referring to?

Comment: Your demonstration is good. [ General solution here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195582/general-proof-for-the-triangle-inequality)

Comment: I removed the stray equals sign. Question for you to consider: was it really necessary to move $|x|$ to the left-hand side?

Comment: Definitely not necessary, but I wanted to make it explicit that I was going to invoke theorem 1 a second time.  Without moving the $|x|$ out of the way, I thought it would be unclear how that side plugs back into theorem 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the triangle inequality twice to get the desired result:

\begin{align*}
|x + y + z| & = |(x + y) + z|\\\\
& \leq |x + y| + |z|\\\\
& \leq |x| + |y| + |z|
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I think I see now, the second application of triangle eq is really inline, or "beside" the $|z|$.  I was (maybe still am) confused here since if the triangle eq was only stating equality, then I see how essentially substituting $|x+y|$ for $|x|+|y|$ inline makes sense, but since triangle eq is an inequality, I'm not clear on how the inline substitution is still good -- I mean, I get that it is, but I don't know how to think about it.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Could think of it simply as adding $|z|$ to both sides of triangle eq which is obviously good.